# Is QPixmap reentrant?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt5.4, reentrancy

I have a program that needs to load *a lot* of QPixmaps. I split the loading of the pixmaps in several jobs using `QtConcurrent::mappedReduced` (I actually load a bunch of `QGraphicPixmapItem`s). The loading function calls *only* the constructors of the `QPixmap`s/`QGraphicItem`s, it does not attempt to perform any drawing, and it does not communicate with the rest of the world (at least through my code) until the loading is finished.

<s>I get some random crashes during the initialization (say 1% of the times)</s>, and helgrind complains about unguarded accesses to `QApplication` from the `QPixmap` and from the main event loop, but it is known that Qt mutexes generally do not mix well with valgrind, so it might be a false positive.

As usual, the Qt documentation is quite unclear on whether `QPixmap` is reentrant or not, that is basically my question.

Comment: qpixmap.cpp contains a private method qt_pixmap_thread_test() that will print a warning to stdout if you are running on a platform that doesn't support the use of QPixmaps outside the main thread.  The implication of that seems to be that if you don't see that warning printed, it is safe to use QPixmaps in other thread (although I doubt it would be safe to draw them into a widget outside the GUI thread of course)

Comment: The question isn't about whether `QPixmap` is reentrant, but whether it's thread-safe. Those are *very different things*. You can have classes that are thread safe but not reentrant, and vice versa. One doesn't necessarily imply the other.

Comment: Of course. I need it to be *reentrant* in my use case. In my application there are no concurrent access to the same object from different threads. Still several *different* QPixmap are constructed from different threads. Hence i need reentrancy.

Comment: I think the docs are pretty clear about this. [*Qt classes are only documented as thread-safe if they are intended to be used by multiple threads. If a function is not marked as thread-safe or reentrant, it should not be used from different threads. If a class is not marked as thread-safe or reentrant then a specific instance of that class should not be accessed from different threads.*](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-reentrancy.html#reentrant)

Answer (score 2):

Well, you get crashes and you ask if it's OK? You already know the answer. It's not OK.

The only question I see here is whether it's a Qt bug. No, it's not.

If you want to load a lot of pixmaps, load them in into `QImages`, and then convert them into the backing store format. There isn't all that much to be gained these days from using a pixmap over an image. As long as the image has the same format as the widget's backing store (cast to `QImage`), you'll have same performance. The `QPixmap` distinction made sense when Qt still used native painting. On Windows and OS X, a pixmap is just a properly formatted `QImage`.

Comment: `There isn't all that much to be gained these days from using a pixmap over an image` Except that QGraphicsPixmapItem requires a pixmap, and  AFAIK there is no QGraphicsImageItem.`

`Well, you get crashes and you ask if it's OK? You already know the answer. It's not OK` It is a large app, a lot of people contributed to the code, and it is a huge spaghetti mess. I am looking for *guarantees*. Does Qt guarantee that I can *construct* a QPixmap from a child thread? Yes or no.

Comment: @sbabbi No. It doesn't. Hence it crashes. You know that already!! It's easy enough to make a `QGraphicsImageItem`. Besides, it's not necessarily safe to instantiate `QGraphicsItem` in non-gui thread *either*. You'd need to audit the code to check that.