# Qt: Preload the qpixmap in another thread?

Tags: c++, qt

The Qt's doc said that QImage cannot be used for hardware acceleration (graphic card.)
And you need to use QPixmap which can be only used in the mainthread.

But my situation is here: I need to get the image from reading a QBytearray. If I convert the QBytearray to qpixmap in the main thread, it is very slow.

So I convert the bytearray to a QImage in the worker thread.
But the doc also said that convertion from QImage to QPixmap is expensive.

So is there any solution that I could use a worker thread to convert the bytearray to image and still plot it with hardware acceleration?
Is openGL the only choice?

Comment: I asked the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29214549/is-qpixmap-reentrant) a while ago. Apparently, despite what reported in the only answer, you can construct a QPixmap from a QImage in another thread, at least on windows.

Answer (score 0):

`QPixmap` represents a platform native pixmap, which enjoys **some degree** of hardware acceleration, but comes at a limitation for some platforms, which may be corner cases, but still apply.

You can chose to stick to what is safe at the cost of being slightly slower, or you can chose to stick to the unsafe if you are only going to target a platform on which it works.

At any rate, `QImage` might be slower, but have you actually established a performance problem? Because you don't have one until you prove that you do. I mean even if slower, `QImage` might still be fast enough, for example on my PC I draw 1 million dots (not pixels) on a 1000x1000 pixmap in 68 msec, and respectively 138 msec for a `QImage` - 138 is like twice as slow but still, I could live with waiting 138 msec for a plot to be drawn.

Comment: So the only way to get things faster is to use opengl?

Comment: As I said, if you do have a performance problem, you could invest the time to do OpenGL drawing, but I am not entirely sure it will be worth the efforts. Also, it depends on what you mean by "using opengl" - because that's a wide topic on its own...

Comment: The problem is that you can't reasonably use QImage to display an image. All the Qt classes (QIcon, QGraphicsPixmapItem, etc.) want a QPixmap. You can rewrite some of them to use QImage but it's not a great solution.

Comment: You can draw a `QImage` onto any `QPaintDevice`